# Content Search Web Part - Pictures slider - auto repeat

Tags: content-search-web-part

is there way or setup where it would rotate back to first image. I have about 10 images and it rotates fine however after the last image the webpart is blank. how to fix this? How to enable auto repeat?

Comment: So when you edit the content search WP, do you see only 10 images only? The reason I am asking this, because, it happened to me that the library had an extra image (corrupted one) and this made the slider not to work correctly. Also, have you customized the display template at all?

Comment: good point. let me check on that